# Error BuildConfig in API_KEY expected ";"

Tags: java

I am preserving my API-KEYS, using local.properties. The application works normally when I run it in the test environment. But when I run "BUILD APK" an error happens.

```
local.properties

API_YOUTUBE = xyxyxyxyxyxxyxyxyxyx--xyxyxyxyxxyxyxy
```

```
build.gradle

buildConfigField "String", "API_YOUTUBE", "${properties.getProperty('API_YOUTUBE')}"
```

```
BuildConfig.java

public static final String API_YOUTUBE = xyxyxyxyxyxxyxyxyxyx--xyxyxyxyxxyxyxy;
```

";" Expected error

Something is wrong related to the double quotes not being in local.properties. However, if I put the quotes, an error occurs in the buildConfigField ("${properties.getProperty('API_YOUTUBE')}"). I've tried everything and I can't do it.

I would like to know if anyone else has had this problem and how they managed to resolve it.

Comment: "I've tried everything". What? Have you tried adding escaped quotes in build.gradle?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work

Comment: How did you try to do that? What happened?